# No graphical side to PHP script

Tags: php, html, user-interface

So I have this piece of code here I got off the internet, it's supposed to export data from mySQL database to an excel file.
The thing is that how am I supposed to trigger this? There's no graphical side of this, no button to trigger the script, nothing. 
How can I make it work?

```
<?PHP
  // Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  include('config.php');
  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  // filename for download
  $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

  $flag = false;
  $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM norse5_proov ORDER BY id") or die('Query failed!');
  while(false !== ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: try learning php instead of copy/pasting. learn some html as well

Comment: I can understand the code pretty well. I'm advanced at HTML and CSS but PHP is programming man...

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that works for me in a commercial app;

```
if($_REQUEST["EXCEL"]){
   header("Content-Type: application/excel");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; FileName=assets.xls");
   header("Cache-Control: private");
   header("Content-Length: ".strLen($data));
   echo $data;
   exit;
}
```

The $data is tab delimited text, but the excel headers open Excel and imports the text

Comment: Just watch out for the warnings that recent versions of MS Excel give when the filename extension doesn't match the actual file format